# Erro ao salvar os dados marcados em um questionario

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou criando um survey que vai salvar os veículos . Para isso tenho que fazer um formulário dividido em várias páginas mas quando eu mudo a pagina os dados marcados nos radio buttons sao perdidos

#### Controller

```
def new_vehicles
   @vehicle = Vehicle.new
   @vehicle.questionnaire = @questionnaire
   @vehicle_types = VehicleType.all      
   render "vehicles/_form"
end
```

#### View

```
<%= nested_form_for(@questionnaire) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :question_2_3, "2.3 A estrada de acesso ao domicílio é transitável no tempo de chuva?" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_2_3 ,"1" %><label >Sempre</label>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_2_3 ,"2" %><label >Não</label>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_2_3 ,"3" %><label >Mais de 50% do tempo das chuvas</label>
  <div class="radioholder clear">
    <label>2.1 Nos últimos 12 meses, anote quantos veículos foram de propriedade dos moradores da casa?</label><br>
    <%= button_to "Inserir +", new_vehicles_questionnaire_path(@questionnaire), remote: true %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Salvar" %>
<% end  %>
```

Salvar o conteudo do questionario antes de direcionar para a pagina veiculos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você durante a criação de um **questionário** você gostaria de adicionar **veículos** a ele. Seria bem fácil se você pudesse criar o **questionário** e depois associar os **veículos**, mas pelo que vi não é o caso.

Vejo outras possibilidades de resolver esse problema, mas julgado que você realmente quer persistir os dados do `radio_button` antes de ir adicionar os **veículos** podemos tentar fazer o seguinte:

Na `action` `new` de `Questionnaire` você deve persistir o objeto e já redirecioná-lo para a área de edição (Não sei se é assim que você já esta fazendo, mas é o primeiro passo)

### Solução 1

Para fazer esse redirecionamento persistente você terá que fazer o submit dessas informações para Quesqionnaire e passar uma informação para que ele saiba que terá que realizar o redirect, por exemplo

Em seu **Button**:

```
<%= f.button "Adicionar Veículo", name: "redirect_to_action[#{questionnaire_vehicles_path(@questionnaire)}]" %>
```

Para essa rota eu aninhei as rotas de vehicles em questionnaire no `routes.rb` além de fazer as devidas alterações nas views, mas isso é outro problema.

```
  resources :questionnaires do
    resources :vehicles
  end
```

E em seu **controller**:

```
  # (...)     

  def update
    if @questionnaire.update(questionnaire_params)
        redirect_to custom_redirect(params)
        # (...)
    end
  end

  # (...)

  private

    def custom_redirect(params)
      if params[:redirect_to_action] and ! params[:redirect_to_action].keys.empty?
        params[:redirect_to_action].keys.first
      else
        @questionnaire
      end
    end
```

Não tem como testar o código pra saber se tem algum erro, mas acho que a mecânica pode ser essa.

### Solução 2

Você pode utilizar um formulário aninhado (`Nested Form`)

**Model Questionnaire**

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicles
end
```

**Model Vehicle**

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :questionnaire
end
```

**questionnaires/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@questionnaire) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question_2_3, "2.3 A estrada de acesso ao domicílio é transitável no tempo de chuva?" %><br>
    <%= f.radio_button :question_2_3 ,"1" %><label >Sempre</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :question_2_3 ,"2" %><label >Não</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :question_2_3 ,"3" %><label >Mais de 50% do tempo das chuvas</label>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :vehicles do |f_vehicle| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f_vehicle.label :model %><br>
      <%= f_vehicle.text_field :model %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f_vehicle.label :color %><br>
      <%= f_vehicle.text_field :color %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f_vehicle.label :year %><br>
      <%= f_vehicle.number_field :year %>
    </div>
  <% end  %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**QuestionnaireController**

```
# (...)

  def edit
    @questionnaire.vehicles.build
  end

# (...)

  def questionnaire_params
    params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:question_2_3, vehicles_attributes: [:model, :color, :year])
  end
```

> PS: Como não tenho ideia de sua real estrutura criei um *crud* com
>   alguns dos dados apresentados e outros dados deduzidos para completar
>   o exemplo.

-

> PS 2: Vi que você utiliza a gem `nested_form` ela pode deixar essa
>   adição de novos `vehicles` mais dinâmicas (você já deve saber disso,
>   provavelmente foi o motivo de adiciona-la ao projeto, mas não custa
>   nada falar)

### Solução 3

Você pode usar `Modals` para carregar o formulário de `Vehicles` e submete-lo associando ao `@questionnaire`, não esquecendo de dar o update na lista de `Vehicles` exibida no formulário de `@questionnaire`